# Extract specific column from a file into a comma separated string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to create an SED command to modify a input file with some conditions explained below.

I have an input file something like below.

List item

```
Rad# ; ID_KEY ; UNIT_ID ; ORGA_ID
1  ; 30000000004 ; 8417920 ; 0001
2  ; 30000000004 ; 8170811 ; 0001
3  ; 30000000004 ; 7709260 ; 0001
4  ; 30000000004 ; 20145598 ; 0001
5  ; 30000000004 ; 1661503 ; 0001
6  ; 30000000004 ; 1445852 ; 0001
7  ; 30000000004 ; 2480684 ; 0001
8  ; 30000000004 ; 8278636 ; 0001
9  ; 30000000004 ; 20102078 ; 0001
10  ; 30000000004 ; 1581292 ; 0001
11  ; 30000000004 ; 20574348 ; 0001
12  ; 30000000004 ; 8057248 ; 0001
----
----
----
98  ; 3000000000 ; 6830310 ; 0007
99  ; 3000000000 ; 7880497 ; 0007
100  ; 3000000000 ; 597529 ; 0007
101  ; 3000000000 ; 702884 ; 0008
----
----
998  ; 3000000000 ; 7907220 ; 0009
999  ; 3000000000 ; 20311746 ; 0007
1000  ; 3000000000 ; 6466985 ; 0007
1001  ; 3000000000 ; 8285052 ; 0007
```

Below are few things I need to do with this file:

1. Remove 1st line completely
2. for the rest lines , I need to retain only number between 2nd and 3rd semicolon.
3. I need to add comma between all the numbers retained from step 2 above and output it to single line with no comma at the end of last number (I want to use it as input to another sql in filter `WHERE IDS IN (<Result>)`) .

Also note that I want to write the output to another text file (create new file or I can have a empty file created at same location as input file) OR modify the same input file.

I also have to have the output file to contain only one number followed by comma. Something like:

List Item

```
8417920,
8170811,
--
8285052
```

Comment: so what would your output should look like? Please also share your attempts on this.

Comment: The output should look like 8417920, 8170811, 7709260, 20145598, 1661503, 1445852, and so on... , 8285052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite nicely in `awk`, in a way that looks quite clear:

```
$ awk -v OFS="," 'NR>1 {f=(f?f OFS:"")$5} END {print f}' file
8417920,8170811,7709260,20145598,1661503,1445852,2480684,8278636,20102078,1581292,20574348,8057248,6830310,7880497,597529,702884,7907220,20311746,6466985,8285052
```

#### Explanation

- `-v OFS=","` set the output field separator to the comma.
- `NR>1 {}` things to be done from the 2nd line.
- `f=(f?f OFS:"")$5` store in the variable `f` all the desired output. If it is appending for the first time, just use the 5th field; otherwise, use the previous stored content.
- `END{}` things to be done after processing the whole file.
- `print f` print the stored string.

---

## Update

> I also have to have the output file to contain only one number
>   followed by comma.

```
$ awk -v OFS="," 'NR>1 {if (f) print f OFS; f=$5} END {print f}' file
8417920,
8170811,
7709260,
...
7907220,
20311746,
6466985,
8285052
```

Store the previous line and print it together with the comma. Finally, print the last one but without that comma.

Comment: This works but I need to write the output to different file or modify the same inout file. Currently this is printing the result to console.

Comment: Update your question with the proper requirements. To redirect into a file, just do `awk '...' file > newfile`.

Comment: I also have to have the output file to contain only one number followed by comma. Something like below
* 8417920,
* 8170811,
* --
* 8285052

Comment: @SandeepDongapure it is not clear what you mean. If it is a new requirement, it may be better to post a new answer mention this one. If it something related, please update your question showing *exactly* how the output should look like. Use the formatting tools for a proper display

Comment: This is related to same topic. I only need to format the output in such a way that each line should have only one number followed by comma. Unfortunately I'm unable to format the output here but hope you know what I meant now.

Comment: @SandeepDongapure it is still not clear what you mean. "Only one number followed by comma"? It is already like this, since we are just getting the number in the 3rd column and printing it comma separated. I don't see the difference with the current aproach.

Comment: I want the printing to move to next line for each number. Let's say if output is something like 1000,2000,3000. Currently this is printed in single line. But I need each number to be printed separately on different line in output line. Meaning '1000,' should be on first line, '2000,' should be on 2nd line in output file and 3000 on 3rd line.

Comment: @SandeepDongapure this changes the current approach completely. Is it the **definite** version? I am not going to change the code eternally when you change the way you want data to be presented.

Comment: Take a look at details in question now. The output is formatted now and I want it to be looking like that. I believe there is way to format the output in same awk command. Please assist

Comment: @SandeepDongapure yep, you formatted it properly. See update in my answer.

Comment: Nevermind - I got what I wanted. Modified the command you provided to add new line after comma. It worked!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sed -n '2~1{s/[^;]*;\([^;]*\);.*/\1,/;H;}; $x;$s/\n//g;s/,$//;$w foo.txt'
```

Explaination:

- `-n` tells sed not to print pattern space for each line
- 2~1 tells sed to execute the following commands for each line begining with 2
- `s/[^;]*;\([^;]*\);.*/\1,/` takes the second text enclosed in `;`
- `H` append to hold space
- `$` at the end
- `x` exchange hold space and pattern space
- `s/\n//g` remove all newlines
- `s/,$//` remove last comma
- `w foo.txt` write pattern space to foo.txt

Comment: Also note that I want to write the output to another text file (create new file or I can have a empty file created at same location as input file).

Comment: Done. Note that there is another answer, but as you asked for sed, I did it with sed.